# switch activity and send string as an extra to another activity

Tags: java, android, string, android-intent, android-activity

I have a `TabLayoutObjectActivity` that shows 2 tabs with a different activity(`TabActivity1` & `TabActivity2`).

I have another activity called `ObjectActivity`.  It contains an array and if it is clicked I want the app to change to the `TabLayoutObjectActivity` (which shows `TabActivity1` first) and sends a string from an array that clicked to `TabActivity1`.

I have tried some code but the app always wants to force close after I click one of the array list.

```
        Intent i = null;
        i = new Intent(this, TabLayoutObjekActivity.class);

        Intent ii = null;
        ii = new Intent(this, TabActivity1.class);
        ii.putExtra("name", String.valueOf(menuArray[position].toString()));

        startActivity(i);
        startActivity(ii);
```

Please give me your opinion how to do this. Thanks :)

Comment: stacktrace!! should really be a dropdown comment on SO

Comment: This code doesnt make sense to be honest.. but still need stacktrace

Answer (score 1):

Refer to [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html). It explains how to solve your problem in detail. onclick even you can handle the issue.